# Add Item from textbox to dropdown and store it in database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have two dropdown list i want to add more item in it through textbox and store them into database

```
protected void ddlDisp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        if (ddlDisp.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CallcenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;            
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
            SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataSet dsSubDisp = new DataSet();

            using (cmd = new SqlCommand("Select distinct CallType,Disposition,SubDisposition,Format from  Loy_DispMstr where CallType=@CallType and SUBFormat=@Format and Disposition = @disposition", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallType",ddlCalltype.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Format", ddlFormat.SelectedItem.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@disposition", ddlDisp.SelectedValue);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dsSubDisp);
               {

                    ddlSubdisp.DataTextField = "SubDisposition";
                    ddlSubdisp.DataValueField = "SubDisposition";
                    ddlSubdisp.DataSource = dsSubDisp.Tables[0];
                    ddlSubdisp.DataBind();

                    ddlSubdisp.Items.Insert(0, "<----Select---->");
                    ddlSubdisp.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    ddlSubdisp.Focus();

                }
            }
```

catch(Exception ex)
            {}
            }

> from this i can save the inserted items from textbox to dropdown
>
> from this i can save the inserted items from textbox to dropdown
>
> from this i can save the inserted items from textbox to dropdown

```
   protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

       if (TextBox1.Text == "" && TextBox2.Text == "")
       {
           Label2.Text = "Enter Value !!";
           TextBox1.Focus();
           TextBox2.Focus();
           Label2.Visible = CheckBox1.Checked;
       }
       else
       {
           ddlDisp.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text);
           ddlSubdisp.Items.Add(TextBox2.Text);
           Label2.Text = "Item Added Successfully !!!";

       }

   }
```

Comment: be clear when you are asking 1.`in it` means do u infer to two dropdowns? and u want to add to the dropdown on adding to the textbox ?
 so you adding with another button such as `save` or  on textchanged event of Textbox ?

Comment: i dnt want to add dropdown. i want to add textbox by which i can add values to dropdown on button click

Comment: did you created 1.Textbox markup and add Textchange event with Postback=true and in that call this  Dropdown binding with adding new item to the dropdown

Comment: i have added textbox whose value comes on dropdown bt the question is how to save it in database

Comment: you need to save the Dropdown selected value or newly added value to the db?

Comment: newly added value

Comment: one way of doing this is , i'm assuming that dropdown values will be in seperate Table so when ever you are binding the value to the Dropdown in Textbox change event , it is good to add that value to the Database. as a seperate insert statement

Comment: can you please explain  me through example

Comment: for sample i need to provide mean i need to know till where you tried , rather than me creating from scratch , thats not how SO works. Because we will not be paid for these tasks . its a Community helping each other

Comment: i have done till showing my textvalue in dropdownlist on button click now only thing is left is saving it in database

Comment: please add that markup in the Question